# Can not connect to Redis Server on another server

Tags: .net, redis

I have installed Redis on my PC and use it ... every things works fine.
now I want to install It on another server.
I installed it and test it on that server and that works fine.
but when I want to use it on my application I get this error.

"Could not connect to Redis at 192.1.100.33:6379: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

server: windows server 2016
pc: windows 10
using c# application .net 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and found my solution
in redis.server.config must bind valid Ip
for example in my case should add :
bind 192.1.100.33 127.0.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to Memurai. It's actively maintained. Never had a problem in over a year